# How can I trigger action in RxJS based on a conditional logic?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, rxjs-observables

What I am trying to do - I need to add conditional check before triggering the api call (getterFunc), which check if data is already present in store or not,  if it’s not then fetch the data from backend. But if it’s available, then simulate the success event and provide store data in payload. Can you help me with what’s exactly wrong am I doing in this implementation

```js
const getTemplateEpic = (getterFunc, initial, success, cancel, failure) => (action$, store) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(initial),
  mergeMap(action => iif(() => Object.keys(store.value.getIn(['whatsApp'].templateListData)).length,
    of({
      type: success,
      payload: { res: store.value.getIn(['whatsApp'].templateListData) }
    }),
    getterFunc('GET', action.payload)
  ).pipe(
    map(response => ({
      type: success,
      payload: { res: response.response },
    })),
    takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(cancel))),
    catchError(error => of({
      type: failure,
      payload: { res: error },
    })
    )
  )
  )
);
```

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? What line or what error it shows?

Comment: It's not showing any error, but when I check redux dev tools, it's stuck at initial action, after that no further actions is getting executed and my loader keeps loading.